# Using modal in isset PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to open a modal when submit is clicked in the table .
I tried to change the animation to `fadeIn` because using fade the modal shows only flash.

The result when I use the `fadeIn` the modal appears but in split second and I did not include any timers or refresh in the whole page.

Can I have a sample code to show the modal and set the conditions in

```
if(isset($_POST['pending']))     {  ...alert ..}
```

or please comment suggestions for this.

Because I am unable to use and view the modal properly.

Note: It has a bootstrap  for the modal  and jquery but I did not include here in the post

```html
 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
{
  echo "<form action='dir_1.php' method='POST'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" /></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
}
```

```html
if(isset($_POST['pending'])){            
            
            echo('                
   <div class="modal fadeIn" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Enter your First and Last Name</h2>
                    <form action="submit_prompt.php" method="post">
                            <p><strong>First Name:</strong><br /> 
                                <input type="text" name="notes" id="input1"/></p>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"  />
                    
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"  />
                <button type="button" onclick="play()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            ');
}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array`<-- Please ***don't use the deprecated `mysql` extension*** It was deprecated years ago, and is removed as of PHP7. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. `PDO` is more commonly used, and has a clean, OO API. `mysqli` is arguably more powerful, but has a messier API. It has both a procedural and OO API, but again: it's more cumbersome to use

Comment: Okay noted. Elias thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried triggering with JavaScript:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['pending'])) { ?>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show')  
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Quick Browser test, testmodal.php:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="modal fadeIn" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Enter your First and Last Name</h2>
            <form action="submit_prompt.php" method="post">
                    <p><strong>First Name:</strong><br /> 
                        <input type="text" name="notes" id="input1"/></p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"  />

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"  />
        <button type="button" onclick="play()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php if(isset($_GET['pending'])) { ?>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show')  
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

In the browser:

```
http://your-domain/testmodal.php?pending=fakevar
```